# Correct response to "Has he lost his keys?"

Tags: sentence-choice, responses

imagine a situation when someone lost their keys but after some time he has found them. What would be the correct response to this question?

"Has he lost his keys?"

Options:

1. "No, he has found them."
2. "Yes but he has found them."
3. "Yes he did but he already found them."

Comment: Could be either 2 or 3

Comment: If the keys are found then by definition they are not lost. A "**Did** you lose your glasses?" B "No, (in the end) I **found** them."

Comment: Number  1. will always be considered ungrammatical because "keys" is plural while the pronoun "it" is singular.

Comment: (4.) He did lose them, but he's found them again. or (5.) Yes, on many occasions, including a recent one. But, as usual, he's found them.

Comment: @apaderno could you please explain why you replaced the [tag:present-perfect] tag with that of "sentence choice, which I'd argue is far broader and less specific than the older one? [tag:sentence-choice] could be anything, about any tense, about adverbs, participles, noun phrases  etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [tag:sentence-choice] is exactly for questions that ask which sentence should be chosen between two or more listed in the question. The question is not about using the Present Perfect, since the difference between the first sentence and the second sentence listed in the question is that the first starts with *No* while the second starts with *Yes*.

Comment: @apaderno you could have also left the present-perfect tag though. Because the question is using the present perfect tense "***Has** he **lost** his keys?*“ And one of the answers is using Past Simple "*Yes, he **did***” Rosie's answer mentions Present situation and Perfective.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In that case, the question should have a tag for *Yes* and *No* too. Tags are for the question, not the given answers. If an answer suggests a different sentence that uses a future expression, the question is not tagged with any *future* tag only for that reason.

Comment: @apaderno I know we have had differences of opinion in the past but surely you can concede that the post uses the Present Prefect tense, and leaving that tag while adding a newer one was an option.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Truly, your first comment was asking why I replaced a tag, not why I did not keep a tag. The possible options, including the totally wrong ones, are more than just two. In my opinion, which specific tense the answer is using is less relevant than the fact the question is asking which answer should be given, between three possible answers. Yes, it is my opinion, but I do not edit a question doing the exact opposite of what, in your opinion, is correct.

Comment: @apaderno  I asked why the tags were swapped because the PP tag was deleted in the first place. If it hadn't been deleted, I would have said nothing. I spent too much creating a scenario where a user found an answer by searching through the tags, when I realised no one does that in the first place. The tags on ELL are pretty useless to begin with, they do help older users find duplicates though.

Comment: Tags can be helpful, but they cannot "capture" every question nuance. They are not surely helpful, when (for example) a question asking how a phrase should be used is tagged [tag:meaning] when the question is not asking about the phrase meaning. A person who wants to ask a question does not probably look for questions using specific tags, but a person interested to understand more about articles could read the questions tagged [tag:articles].

Answer (score 1):

Any of these would be valid answers.

One could quibble that if he lost the keys and later found them, that it's not accurate to say "no", as that implies he never lost them. But on the other hand we're talking about the present state, "has he lost his keys?" would normally be taken to mean "are they lost now?" You could really get into technicalities on this. Like if the question was, "Did he lose his keys yesterday?", I think it would be inaccurate to say "no" just because he's found them since then.

This is the sort of thing that could easily turn into word games and technical nitpicking. Ask a politician a question like this and you might have to study his answer very carefully. Like President Bill Clinton once famously claimed that he hadn't lied in a previous statement and went into a discussion of the definition of the word "is".

Comment: Some people differentiate "lost" meaning permanently without (e.g. you dropped them somewhere in a city and will never get back), and "mislaid" or "misplaced" meaning temporarily without but probably findable (e.g. if you left them somewhere at home and will find them if you have a look). So if you find them, you did not lose them. This is pedantry, but I have heard people say it.

Comment: @StuartF I've heard plenty of people say things like, "I lost this yesterday but then I found it again." I don't think most people understand "lost" to mean "lost forever". But depending on the wording, one might take it to mean "don't know where they are right now", as opposed to, "there was a time in the past when you didn't know where they are".

Answer (score 0):

2. 

The question uses the perfect tense* and thus indicates that the question's focus is on the present situation (even though it relates to the possibility of something having happened in the past). So the answer should have the same focus, and should therefore also use the perfect tense*. So 2.

- In another model of tense and aspect, this is termed the present tense in the perfective aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking only the first would be perfectly grammatically correct, since the current state of the keys is "found", so we can't really say he *has lost* them (present perfect) - that would indicate they're still lost. We can say that he *lost* them (past simple); that doesn't make any statement about later development of the situation.

And "has he?" doesn't pair with "yes, he did" but only either "yes, he has" or "no, he hasn't".

In practice, people don't always speak perfectly correctly, though.